# Type mismatch error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
1.Dim destbook As Workbook

2.Dim destsheet As Worksheet

3.Set destbook = Workbooks("Book1")

4.Set destsheet = destbook.Sheets(1)

5.Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6").Select

6.ct = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).count + 1

7.destbook.Activate

8.Workbooks(destbook).Sheets(destsheet).Range("A" + ct).Select

9.Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Here, when i execute this code, it shows an error saying "type mismatch" on line 8.

Can u help??...

Comment: Main problem is you're using .Select..What are you trying to copy exactly?

Comment: You might also want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "destbook" and "destsheet" as the indexes for "Workbooks" and "Sheets", but they are actually themselves of type "Workbook" and "Worksheet" as you've defined them in lines 1 and 2.  Change line 8 to: `destsheet.Range("A" + ct).Select`.

Comment: You should also change line 5 to "destsheet.Range("C6").Select"

Comment: it again shows the same error.Do u think there is a problem with the range which i provided??...

Comment: You should use "&" instead of "+" to concatenate strings.  It may be thinking you're trying to add the numeric value ct to the string "A".  Try "A" & ct instead.

Comment: Actually, what am I talking about, you can't reference a range like that.  Try this: destsheet.Columns(, ct + 1).Select.  1 represents the first column, i.e. "A".

Answer (score 2):

You should change + to &

> Workbooks(destbook).Sheets(destsheet).Range("A" & ct).Select

Answer (score 1):

As most folks have already pointed out, you need to change the way you are referencing the desired destination cell.  Either you can switch over to an ampersand (&), or change to just a Cells(row,col) reference as you are only updating a single cell (see code below).  You should also consider slimming down your code to make it a bit more efficient.

```
Dim destbook As Workbook
Dim destsheet As Worksheet

Set destbook = Workbooks("Book1")
Set destsheet = destbook.Sheets(1)

'See my note below
destbook.Activate
destsheet.Range("C6").Select
ct = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count + 1
destsheet.Cells(ct, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Notes:
- Line 5 should be changed to use your variables destbook and destsheet.  Note that you'll need to move line 7 up to initially Activate your Workbook and then you can reference your Worksheet destsheet.
- At the "see my note below", you should probably be copying some value from somewhere, otherwise you'll run into a new error upon your PasteSpecial command.
- You should combine line 8 and line 9 together, unless you are planning on reusing the selection from line 8 in some other code (that you have not provided here).

Hope this helps.